# Break a huge json file into separate files

Tags: javascript, json, r

I have a huge json file saved locally around `700MB`. I can't handle it.

Is it possible to break it into 10 separate folder but every file have a full json note have a json have the first half to one file and the other to the next?

Comment: This part is a bit confusing... "every file have a full json note have a json have the first half to one file and the other to the next".  Can you reword?  Also, the structure of the of the file and what you want to do with it once split will probably play into how, or if it can be split.

Comment: @DerekMcCraeNorton thank you for your comment. Here is the file I try to disjoin http://werobots.io/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/Kickstarter_Kickstarter.json_.zip note if you open it you have to delete some lines from the start and the end because it is note  clear json if you don't remove them

Comment: of course I can reword: I mean that the json have a structure and when I tried to seperate my file depending on lines or volume the json for example may have 6 value and disjoin it the 3 value go to the first file and the other 3 go to the second so the json lose the full information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure of your JSON file allows for simple slicing: it contains several chunks of "projects" (7097 to be exact). These "projects" are the highest level and contain itself a different amount of individual projects.

It is quite easy to rip the large file at these seam-lines apart, a couple lines of Perl will do so (Perl because it is available for a large choice of operating systems and handles large files quite easily):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
my $flag = 0;
my $count = 0;
my $start = "Kickstarter_Kickstarter_";
my $ending = "_.jison";
my $filename = "";
open (FILE, '<', 'Kickstarter_Kickstarter.json') 
                        or die "file opening failed: $!";
while (<FILE>) {
    if (/"projects": \[/){
        if($flag == 0){
            $flag = 1;
            $filename = $start.$count.$ending;
        open (CHUNK, '>>', $filename) 
                    or die "file opening failed: $!";
        print STDOUT "Writing a chunk to ".$filename."\n";
        $count++;
        print CHUNK "{ ".$_;
        next;
        } 
    if ( $flag == 1){
            close (CHUNK) or die "file closing failed: $!";
            $flag = 0;
        }
    }
    if(tell(CHUNK) != -1){
        print CHUNK $_ unless /^\,{/;
    }

close (FILE) or die "file closing failed: $!";
```

(will only work for this specific file!)

This will place every of these "projects" chunks into its own, numbered file. You can do what you want with it (put them into ten folders, for example), but I would recommend to use the JSON parser you are most familiar with and index these files, that is: choose one or more of the entries (e.g.: id, name, goal, created_it and so on) and make one file per entry for connecting entries with the individual files. That way you only have to search these small files instead of the whole heap.

I have not checked it but some entries might have multiple occurrences (e.g.: you might find several people named Smith) so simple tuples will most probably not do it.